# How to use the org.json Java library with Java 7

Tags: java, json, org.json

I need some simple JSON parsing in my application and the [Douglas Crockford library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) seems exactly what I need.

However, I seem to be running into a problem. I'm getting the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/json/JSONObject : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

I Googled around a bit and I get the impression that this is due to some version incompatibility. I've tried changing Java versions but it doesn't seem to help. I'm using Java 7 and Java 7 features in my program and ultimately I want to use Java 7.

How can I resolve this issue?

PS: I looked at Jackson and GSON and definitely don't want to use either so please don't suggest as an alternative.

Comment: `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` indicates that that library was compiled with Java 8.  Can you get the [source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) and recompile the library for your version?

Comment: that's do-able, but kinda' goes around the point of using a package manager...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Have you tried using an older version of the package?

Try: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107

Comment: Just trying this and seems to work. It's a shame, even though I can't tell for sure, I don't think the library "needs" Java 8, so compiling it for Java 8 seems quite unnecessary.

Comment: @Luke Well as MichaelT said, if you really want to use the newest version you can compile the sources yourself

Comment: Yep. Understood, but I prefer to manage dependencies through a dependency manager (such as Maven).

Comment: Verified that version 20140107 works using Maven 3.1.1 / Tycho 0.22.0 / JDK 7_17. Only question really is the MIT/DoNoEvil license - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford#.22Good.2C_not_Evil.22

Comment: still works with jdk1.7.0_76.  i wish maven had a place for "last version compatible with java7", that's twice i've gotten burned with a newest version and searched around for usable versions.  and, the github page now says douglas crockford is looking for a new maintainer as of 2015-02-06...

Answer (score 3):

Since your are using JDK1.7, change to the older version will work!

```
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: where do I add this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use version
20230618    for Java 6 or 7.
There were a few older versions where they accidentally broke Java 6, but Java 7 support should be ok until 20230618

org.json
json
20230618

See their release notes:
https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/docs/RELEASES.md

20231013    First release with minimum Java version 1.8. Recent commits, including fixes for CVE-2023-5072.

20230618    Final release with Java 1.6 compatibility. Future releases will require Java 1.8 or greater.