# JRE System Library - Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-7, m2eclipse

I did the downgrade of java 8 to java 7 and I am unable to run my project.

My eclipse configurations are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.usp.icmc.jenkins.saucelabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>JenkinsSaucelabs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JenkinsSaucelabs</name>
    <description>JenkinsSaucelabs</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <!-- Dependente da versão da JDK -->
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
            <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>TesteJSONSauceLabs</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I have tested the alternatives of posts:

[Eclipse JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926798/eclipse-jre-system-library-j2se-1-5)

[No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra)

Stacktracer:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/json/JSONObject : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at br.usp.icmc.teste.ConnectionRestClient.getSaucelabsJobsByID(ConnectionRestClient.java:30)
    at br.usp.icmc.teste.TestePrincipal.main(TestePrincipal.java:8)
```

Why am I receiving an UnsupportedClassVersionError exception with Unsupported major.minor version 52.0? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Is there any Class name in error message?

Comment: Tested also enter a JRE and JDK both in version 7 in the build path of the project and still not worked.

Comment: I updated the question with the full stacktracer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your application with the incorrect version of java, or some of the dependencies you are using are compiled for java 8.

Check that your JAVA_HOME is pointing to the correct java installation and that Eclipse truely uses Java 7.

Comment: My $JAVA_HOME in .bashrc file: export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80"

Comment: I'm in doubt dependence net.sf.json-lib requiring <classifier> jdk15 </ classifier> to work.

Comment: I found the dependence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352672/how-to-use-the-org-json-java-library-with-java-7

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Adrian B., now it's all working!

Comment: Is there a way to find out which dependencies are suffering from this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After you changed the Java version being used in the POM file, did you refresh the project's dependencies in Eclipse?

In Eclipse Luna (and possibly Eclipse Mars), this is done by pressing Alt-F5 or by right clicking a Maven project, choosing the Maven menu, then clicking the Update Projects button.

This brings up a new dialog that looks something like this:

[image: Update Maven Project]

All Maven projects in the current Eclipse workspace should be shown.  In the above example, this is a parent project with multiple child projects.

You should select all Maven projects in your workspace, then click OK.

This should force Maven to refresh all the dependencies for the project... including the Java version Maven is attempting to use for the project.

Comment: I followed your suggestion Powerlord and even still not working.

Comment: When I run maven install the eclipse he builds my project successfully normally. But when running I get the exception.

Comment: Thank you for explanation Powerlord, It worked perfectly.